# Issue when creating application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Just followed an online tutorial (http://amunategui.github.io/aws-beanstalk/) to create a simple Hello World Python app and wanna upload it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I followed all the steps. After running `eb create`, I got the following errors lines:

```
2020-06-08 06:52:30    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-gnqy9jbs4g-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-1FOX4Q2UOT7A4
2020-06-08 06:52:30    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-gnqy9jbs4g-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-DJZBR1IJKDMY
2020-06-08 06:52:36    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ba7decf4ea86eedc] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-06-08 06:52:36    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-06-08 06:53:39    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: ServiceError - Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

Right now the application is showing as 'Severe'. Tapping the Elastic Beanstalk URL just gave me an HTTP 503 error.

It sounds like to me it's something wrong with the CloudWatch setup. Does anyone know what the problem is?